# multer upload returns 500 with python post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to upload a single image using python code to a node js express server. The python code is:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:9000/testAPI/uploadphoto'
files = {'file': ('photo', open('test.jpg', 'rb'))}

ret = requests.post(url, files=files)
print ret
```

For the app.js, it is mostly following the default template:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser')

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var testAPIRouter = require("./routes/testAPI");
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
//app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use("/testAPI", testAPIRouter);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

and I am using the router testAPI for handling the POST:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var router = express.Router();

// SET STORAGE
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, '/uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var filename = file.originalname;
        var fileExtension = filename.split(".")[1];
        cb(null, Date.now() + "_" + filename);
    }
  });

  var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("test");
    res.send('API is working properly');
});

router.post('/uploadphoto', upload.single('photo', (req, res, next) => {

    const file = req.file;
    if (!file) {
        const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
        error.httpStatusCode = 400
        return next(error)
    }

    res.send('Photo uploaded');

}));

module.exports = router;
```

When I run the python code, the server returns 500. In my node js directory, I have an uploads folder created.

Comment: hm, does the uploads folder need to be under public folder?

Answer (score 0):

At the first you should run your node server project in port 9000

Your npm start probably calls your bin/www file. Which contains the listen invocation to start your app.

Many people set up their app this way. eg. app.js to define and configure their app, and something like bin/www to actual get the server running. This way they can include the app.js into other parts, say tests, without actually starting the server when you require it.

Figured it out. Since my server is started in the bin/www file as opposed to the app.js file, from the terminal I went into my bin directory and then called

```
node wwww
```

or

```
nodemon www
```

or add this code to the app.js and then run it with `node app.js` to listen port 9000

const port = 9000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))

Comment: I could get the express server to run, the error happens when I did the python POST program